# When sending data through openfeign, null is received

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, openfeign

I have a trouble. When i send dto by feign clients like this:

```
@FeignClient(url = "${external.service.cloudbeds.url}", name = "CloudbedsIntegrationClient")
public interface CloudbedsIntegrationClient {

@PostMapping(value = "/integration/cloudbeds/lock-code")
String sendLockCodeToCloudbeds(@RequestBody LockCodeDto lockCodeDto);
```

}

and use this method

```
cloudbedsIntegrationClient.sendLockCodeToCloudbeds(lockCodeDto);
```

i try recive this data on localhost:8081 by this RestController

```
@PostMapping("/integration/cloudbeds/lock-code")
public void cloudbeds(LockCodeDto dto){
   log.info(dto + "это с клауд");
}
```

but i get null

```
2021-03-10 10:45:55.817  INFO 27780 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] c.e.feigntest.FeigntestApplication       : LockCodeDto(bookingId=null, codeValue=null)это с клауд
```

what i do wrong?

Comment: LockCodeDto has setters? Getters?.  Did you actually set values to your LockDto before sending it through the sendLockCodeToCloudbeds

Comment: i use lombok annotation @Data
`@Data
@Builder
public class LockCodeDto {
    private String bookingId;
    private String codeValue;
}`

Comment: shouldnt your public void cloudbeds(@RequestBody LockCodeDto dto) actually have a @RequestBody as well>

Answer (score 0):

When you receive your request in the `localhost:8081` application, you need to put the `@RequestBody` before the `LockCodeDto`